# Why is my Data not being added to my dbo.table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to populate a local mdf database that consists of 2 tables. the first table contains "top lvl" data and the second table is "referring" to the first.

The problem is: the code doesn't fill the second table and I don't understand why. The table only displays one row with NULL values. I'm sorry if this is a double post, but I tried to find an answer and all I got was confused. If you are able to provide a solution, please elaborate as much as possible. Thank you in advance.

Here I pass in a DataTable from a previous method (it is full with the values i would like to insert in the database. I checked.)

public void InsertTrackDataToSql(DataTable dtXL)

Here the full code:

```
    public void InsertTrackDataToSql(DataTable dtXL)
    {
        DataRow[] selectRows = dtXL.Select();
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection();
        sqlCon.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        sqlCon.Open();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 7; i < selectRows.Length; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = selectRows[i];
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Track (CUE_NR,TRACK_ID,TITLE,ARTIST,LABEL,COMPOSER,PUBLISHER,TC_IN,TC_OUT,DURATION,FILENAME) VALUES (@CUE_NR,@TRACK_ID,@TITLE,@ARTIST,@LABEL,@COMPOSER,@PUBLISHER,@TC_IN,@TC_OUT,@DURATION,@FILENAME)", sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUE_NR", row.ItemArray[0]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRACK_ID", row.ItemArray[1]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TITLE", row.ItemArray[2]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARTIST", row.ItemArray[3]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LABEL", row.ItemArray[4]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPOSER", row.ItemArray[5]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PUBLISHER", row.ItemArray[6]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TC_IN", row.ItemArray[7]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TC_OUT", row.ItemArray[8]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DURATION", row.ItemArray[9]);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME", "Filename");
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("WhyNot: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Just stop using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/). If you run your program with that connection string and you check the data from SSMS or another program, you'll be dealing with two different copies of the database. Messy and error-prone.

Comment: No Exception? Are you 100% sure `dtXL` has rows?

Comment: When you step through this in the debugger, what specific behavior does it exhibit?  Does the loop have any elements to iterate over?  Is the SQL command executed at all?  What are the values it uses?  We can't debug this for you.

Comment: int i = 7; i < selectRows.Length are you sure selectRows has more than 7 entries?

Comment: Consider passing the datatable directly to sql.  If you need to filter the first 7 rows, have that happen before this function is called.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); return 1?

Comment: Oh my, so many answers. @Aaron thx for your suggestion. I'll look into that. I basically copy pasted the string from the settings of the DB.

Comment: @mxmissile/@Steve: sry, no errors no nothing. I can run the code just fine. dtXL is full(i used another method before i created this one, and displayed my values with debug.writeline). I start at i = 7 because the values before that are not needed(i goes up to 42 btw).

Comment: @Joe thx for the suggestion. I'll look into that.

Comment: @moi_meme: How would I test the return value of ExecuteNonQuery();? THX for all the answers.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I tried to understand the approach you posted, but didn't fully get what the string should look like in the end. I followed this guide and got the above result. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p5.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thx man. You were spot on! I changed AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf; to AttachDbFilename=C:\MyPath\MyDatabase.mdf; and now the table fills. Just amazing thank you so much. I hope it is the proper way to do this. If it is you can answer my question so I can give you points.